# POCO libraries: possible to set UDP Source port?

Tags: c++, udp, poco-libraries

I'm using the POCO c++ libraries, and I'm at a loss. Is there any way to set the source port when sending a UDP datagram? It looks like it's always set to the destination port, but surely this is possible.

My code looks something like this:

```
Poco::Net::SocketAddress bcast("255.255.255.255", m_txPort);
DatagramSocket dgs  = DatagramSocket(bcast,false);
dgs.setBroadcast(true);
dgs.sendTo(data,dataLength, broad);
```

Failing that, I might be switching to Boost - I assume boost can do this, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should work just fine; you pass a SocketAddress with the source address and port into your `DatagramSocket` constructor which says which local address to bind to; following your example;

```
Poco::Net::SocketAddress sourceAddress("255.255.255.255", source_port);
DatagramSocket dgs(source_address,false);
```

Then you pass a separate socketaddress with the destination address and port into `SendTo`.

```
Poco::Net::SocketAddress destAddress(destination_address, destination_port);
dgs.setBroadcast(true);
dgs.sendTo(data,dataLength, destAddress);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, when I try to use a different SocketAddress in the sendTo than the one used to create the DatagramSocket, I don't get any packets at all. (I'm watching with Wireshark). I agree that this seems like the right way to do it - I just can't make it work.

Comment: I'm mistaken - You're quite correct. It just took me a bit to get to working (for an unrelated reason, I needed reuseAddress set True in two places, and that was causing a pile of trouble).